# What are good NoSQL and non-relational database solutions for audit/logging database

Tags: logging, nosql, audit-trail

What would be suitable database for following? I am especially interested about your experiences with non-relational [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) systems. 
Are they any good for this kind of usage, which system you have used and would recommend, or should I go with normal relational database (DB2)?

I need to gather audit trail/logging type information from bunch of sources to a
centralized server where I could generate reports efficiently and examine what is happening in the system.

Typically a audit/logging event would consist always of some mandatory fields, for example

- globally unique id (some how generated by program that generated this event)
- timestamp
- event type (i.e. user logged in,  error happened etc)
- some information about source (server1, server2)

Additionally the event could contain 0-N key-value pairs, where value might be up to few kilobytes of text.

- It must run on Linux server
- It should work with high amount of data (100GB for example)
- it should support some kind of efficient full text search
- It should allow concurrent reading and writing
- It should be flexible to add new event types and add/remove key-value pairs to  new events. Flexible=no changes should be required to database schema, application generating the events can just add new event types/new fields as needed.
- it should be efficient to make queries against database. For reporting and exploring what happened.  For example:

  - How many events with type=X occurred in some time period.
  - Get all events where field A has value Y.
  - Get all events with type X and field A has value 1 and field B is not 2 and event occurred in last 24h

Answer (score 3):

The two I've seen used successfully are [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) and [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/).

Comment: MongoDB is Fantastic for Logging: http://blog.mongodb.org/post/172254834/mongodb-is-fantastic-for-logging

Answer (score 2):

> should I go with normal relational database (DB2)?

Yes, you should!  If you just want to store stuff and scan it, you might as well write to a file.  Very fast, no overhead!  But the minute you want to summarize data over time (last 24h, or between time t and t+1), the more you care about the data as something other than lines of text, no question a proper RDBMS is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

We used [Redis](http://redis.io/) to do all our centralized logging for all our app servers at mflow.com. It is very fast, which based on [these benchmarks](http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks) it does about 110000 SETs per second, about 81000 GETs per second. It has a VM implementation (if your dataset exceeds available memory) which swaps out un-frequented values out to disk.

It's an advanced data-structures server that can store any binary-safe data with native support for strings, lists, sets, sorted sets and hashes. Based on discussions on the mailing list it is heavily used by a lot of people to store analytics.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking a look at logs database I work on - [VictoriaLogs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/VictoriaLogs/). It fits the following requirements:

- It accepts log lines with arbitrary number of fields. It doesn't need any configuration for this.
- It allows fast full-text search across all the fields without the need to configure anything.
- It runs on Linux amd64 (as well as on other operating systems and architectures).
- It is optimized for efficient storing and processing terabytes of logs on a single node. It compresses stored logs, so they occupy much lower amounts of disk space than the original uncompressed logs.
- It supports concurrent data ingestion and querying.
- It integrates well with traditional command-line tools for logs analysis - head, less, grep, awk, jq, etc. See [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/VictoriaLogs/querying/#command-line).
- It provides easy to use query language for logs - [LogsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/VictoriaLogs/LogsQL.html).